# LXC and proxying port 22 (ssh)

Tags: linux, nginx, ssh, iptables, lxc

I have installed LXC on my Ubuntu 12.04 server and have created a couple of containers. I have only 1 external IP address, thus I am using nginx on my host machine to proxy HTTP requests from certain hosts to the relevant containers.

I'm only vaguely familiar with nginx and the concept of proxying in general, but from my research it appears I cannot proxy SSH.

Thus I have to port forward using IP tables. This is less than ideal, as I will have to use different ports to SSH into the different containers.

Ideally I'd like to proxy port 22 on certain hostnames to the relevant container, but I don't see how this is possible.

For example:

- `ssh host1` should proxy to container "container1" on port 22.
- `ssh host2` should proxy to container "container2" on port 22.

Is this possible?